# I can't open file on my Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm developing an android application which needs to open a csv file. The file is selected by the user by means of the File Explorer.

On my real device I have no problems, but on my emulator something isn't working because when I click with the mouse on the csv file, the touch seems ignored.

[image]

When I touch that file on my real device the control returns to my application, but on the emulator nothing happens!

code:

```
    Intent x = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    x.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    x.setType("text/csv");
    startActivityForResult(x, CSV_FILE_SCELTO);
```

Comment: Asking a question on this site without a code snippet is a vain attempt. Please provide the code where you read a file

Comment: This will not help because my code is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file in the screenshot is disabled/grayed, enabled files are black and has meta data like files size, etc. Files that do not match the mime type are disabled/grayed and can't be selected. Are you using the same file in both emulator and real device? I suspect the file on the emulator does not have the correct mime type.

Try to change the mime filter to all files like below

```
Intent x = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
x.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
x.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(x, CSV_FILE_SCELTO);
```

If this changes works than it is mime type issue.